# Google App Engine vs Tomcat

Tags: google-app-engine, tomcat

I was able to create the basic 'hello world' program.

When I tried to understand the difference between a cloud and a server I learned that Cloud is where you have an access to virtual instance created exclusively for you and you are free to choose and install software of your choice.Why Google App Engine(GAE) is used widely where as tomcat is not used. What are major differences between GAE and Tomcat?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please read this guide when you are asking questions next time... I am trying to save you from down-votes. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Cloud* is [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/products/) at this case. App Engine is just one of their services.

App Engine is a platform to build your apps on top of it. A *Platform As A Service* or *PaaS*. It simplifies the process of building a scalable application, and you should use it when you understand what you really need and understand principles of scalable application.

Tomcat is a Java web container, and there're many alternatives. Google App Engine is using Jetty. You could actually use it with Tomcat by using Flexible VM, though it doesn't make much sense.

App Engine is not about web server, it's a set of services that helps you to build a scalable app. It includes Memcache, Datastore, Task Queue, Images API, deployments tools and versioning, CDN for static files, and most important *automatic scale*.

Actually you aren't limited to App Engine on Google Cloud Platform. There is more traditional service, like own server in the cloud, called [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/). There you can run your Tomcat or anything else.

Comment: May I suggest you elaborate on the actual question, which is the difference between gae and tomcat. Simply put: both provide Java EE containers (gae as a service, the other as a product). GAE adds some restrictions in order to be scalable and gives you things like memcache and datastore on top.

Comment: Can you please say me just difference between GAE and Tomcat. Also why GAE is used everywhere.

Comment: Tomcat is a Java web container. Google App Engine is using Jetty as web container.
Also, GAE isn't used widely, it's quite opposite, it's user very rarely and Tomcat is most used web container

Comment: Ok thank you. Am from India we use Google App Engine as a web container in Eclipse to create web applications and deploy them. So just I asked what is the difference between them.

Comment: So basically you're using Jetty instead of Tomcat, that's it. Jetty is simple and lightweight, also it's part of Eclipse, so it's a reason to use it for development. But you don't need to use GAE if you just want a lightweight web container, use plain Jetty - http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/

Comment: Thank you. Really it is helpful.